# How to create a ppt slideshow like this?

Tags: powerpoint

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/humphries/research/seminars/SoupScience09.pdf

Seems that I have noticed bundles of ppt of this style( Some blue background, in pdf), is there a templat for this ppt( I am about to give some report)?Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These slides are made using the Beamer class in LaTeX.

More info:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29)

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer